# PATA IDE 44pin connector name

Tags: ide

Need to build an SPI adapter that uses same pitch connector as PATA IDE 44pin hdd (old laptop hdds), but with different pin count. All i find is "ide connector" which isnt helpful at locating 5x2pin female plug of this kind.

SPI connector in question is not replaceable, as it sits on integrated stepper motor driver board, cant replace it to larger pitch, need to build an adapter...

Who manufactures this type of connector ? Whats the technical term for it besides "ide connector" ?

Comment: *Whats the technical term for it besides "ide connector" ?* It is common "44 pin IDC (2 mm pitch) connector".

Answer (score 0):

I think the technical term is an ["insulation displacement connector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector), although that's more about how it attaches to the ribbon cable itself, but it seems to have a fairly standard general shape, mainly varying in pin count and dimensions.

According to Wikipedia, laptop IDE connectors are "2.00 mm pitch, 44 pins, 2×22 (2 rows of 22 pins)" (see the "Common layouts" section), and I think that the information you'll need to provide to a manufacturer.